# Cannot use Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy in CRM 2013 plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

This question scares me because of how little I can find in online searches regarding it. The long story short is that I am attempting to write a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 plugin and the "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy" class is already in the "References" folder. However, when I type "using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy" I get the intellisense informing me that there is no ".Proxy" option. Literally, the only one that comes up is "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages."

This is baffling me because I am connecting to an on-premise 2013 installation, using Visual Studio 2012, the CRM SDK for Dynamics 2013, and my Framework is set to 4.5.

I simply cannot think of anything else. Thank you all for any help you can offer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll` contains only these two namespaces:

1. Microsoft.Crm.Sdk
2. Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334621.aspx

use these namespace and you are ok

Comment: The page on creating early bound entity classes says:

"The following lists assemblies that must be referenced in your project when you use the generated code file.
•Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll
•Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll"

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I accidentally hit enter before finishing. So just add "using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk" and I am fine?

Comment: both
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;